# Crash reported in play console for incorrect app version

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am facing a strange issue as below:

I have an very old version of my app say version 7.x on end user devices.
Right now I have published version 16.X in production, not containing any code but just a empty hollow app(no code at all).

But somehow when I published this new version to play store I am seeing crash with a stack-trace of my 7.X version logged against my new 16.X version. The 7.X version of my app is no longer available in my play console.

Stack Trace for issue is as below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4519)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:144)

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1339)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5219)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:898)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:693)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

  at android.content.ContentResolver.bulkInsert (ContentResolver.java:1264)

  at com.b.a.a.b.a (SourceFile:168)

  at com.abc.pqr.database.e.e (SourceFile:251)

  at com.abc..DiscoverApplication.a (SourceFile:93)

  at com.abc..DiscoverApplication.onCreate (SourceFile:84)

  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1011)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4516)
```

Is this a known issue in play console or there is some issue while upgrading my app from 7.X to 16.X ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the first thing why crash log for your first version? if your old version updated with the latest one but what about who already not updated your app means possible cash also play store log crash because of old version user.

Also, possible cash is you have not any codding but sometimes memory leak problem generates crash when your app in background for too much time.

Batter thing is integrating some crash logs like `firebase` or `fabric` crash analytics which will give full information.

Comment: If I understood it correctly , what you are saying is that it can be a possible crash while my app is in background? but to have a crash I must have code in first place and if the stack trace is from my old app , should it not be logged for my older version? Also does app update result in older version process creation? because it is important that old app version process is created while updating the app in order to crash it this way, but still can't understand it being logged against my new app version.